# How to append empty or null values without quote in uniVocity CsvWriter

Tags: java, csv, univocity

Im trying to append row, using CSVWriter by uniVocity

When i set

`settings.setQuoteAllFields(true);`

then all fields are quoted, this is logical, but can i set any settings NOT to apply quotes in empty or null fields?

For example, when i call

`String stringRow = writer.writeRowToString(new String[] {"null","","","123"})`

the stringRow is

`"";"";"";"123"`

but i need

`;;;"123"`

How can i set this?

Answer (score 0):

Author of the library here. Currently there is no such option. You'd have to write the CSV by hand.

Comment: ok, done by hands, but also will wait for vesion 3.0.0 with this upgradings